# imessage won't send or receive on my mac

Tags: mac, messages

I am trying to link up with my wife at home (send IM). I am on a platform in Brazil and am hooked up to the platform network via an ethernet cable.

When I try to send to my wife's mac I get a red explanation mark saying the message was not sent, and I receive nothing from my wife.

Any ideas?  Does iMessage work with WiFi only or something?

Answer (score 1):

There’s currently a bug with iMessage in iOS 7 that is preventing iMessages from being sent/received. If your wife is on iOS 7, she can try turning iMessage off, resetting her network settings under General ⇒ Resets, then turning iMessage back on. This has worked for some users. iOS 7.0.3 is expected to address this bug next week.